# App is not opening after build and installing, Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am making the Carpooling app but when I run the code the app builds successfully and installs too but when I click on the app nothing happens after debugging the following error is shown

[image]

Comment: Please copy error text into the question, instead of taking picture of it, because search engines won't find that

Answer (score 0):

i see an error that say  com.google.firebase.auth not found

Look at your app-level build.gradle file. Usually shown as build.gradle (Module: app). Check if it has the two lines mentioned below. If there's none, add those.

```
dependencies {
// ...
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
}
```

if the both are mention and not work you have two option

Option 1: Go to Firebase Console < Authentication < SIGN-IN METHOD, and see if you are using it in the Anonymous state. If you are, disable that and enable Email/Password or whichever login method you are using.

Option 2: Check if the device you are testing with is running Google Play Services 9.0.0 or later.

Comment: both mentioned dependencies are implemented but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup.

See latest dependency of firebase authentication.
Add it into your project and then build it.
Hope it works .

Comment: all dependencies are implemented and upto date. still no working